# Heads or Tails / Coin-flip program

Tags: python

I want to write a coin flip or "Heads or Tails" program, but when I run it, it only gets either heads or tails everytime. I can't see why, it's a logical error so I find it hard to spot.

```
import random

flips = 1

coin = random.randint(1,2)

heads = 0
tails= 0 

while flips <= 100:
     if coin == 1:
        print("Heads")
        heads += 1
        flips +=1
     elif coin == 2:
        print("tails")
        tails += 1
        flips +=1

print("You got", heads, "heads and", tails,"tails!")


input("Exit")
```

Comment: You never call `random.randint` again so of course you'll never get a new random value. Your while loop isn't correct as you're doing `while flips == 100` rather than `while flips <= 100`.

Comment: You flip a coin, and then repeatedly ask whether it was heads or tails. You need to keep flipping that coin.

Comment: Imagine you were doing this in real life. Your current "algorithm" is that you flip a coin once, leave it on the table and keep looking back at it. Why be surprised that it hasn't changed?!

Comment: So where do I put the second random.randint() ?

Comment: You need to do it repeatedly. Where in your code are things being done repeatedly?

Comment: You don't need a second one, just *move the first one!*

Comment: So I put it under the while flips <= 100: ! :D

Comment: Relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Trying printing the value of `coin` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Python removes a lot of code writing that you have to do in other languages.  This program is only three lines.  Using the `random()` method, you're able to do this in a very simple matter.

Here is my code.

```
import random 
coin_flip = ['heads','tails'] 
print random.choice(coin_flip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

flips = 1
heads = 0
tails= 0

while flips <= 100:
    coin = random.randint(1,2)
    flips +=1
    if coin == 1:
        print("Heads")
        heads += 1
    elif coin == 2:
        print("tails")
        tails += 1

print("You got " + str(heads) +  " heads and " + str(tails) + " tails!")
raw_input("Exit")
```

Edits i made:

1. put coins variable in loop so that a new random value is assigned on every call.

Comment: Not only have you broken the code, you haven't explained what you've changed and why

Comment: If you're going to try and FGITW it for quick-and-easy rep, please try to at least make sure your code works. Also, some explanation is really necessary otherwise you're not helping the OP at all, you're purely doing it for your own rep-seeking reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

flips = 0
heads = 0
tails = 0
while flips < 100:
    if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
        print("heads")
        heads += 1
    else:
        print("tails")
        tails += 1
    flips += 1

print("you got ", heads," heads, and ", tails," tails!")
input ("exit")
```

Changes made: starts from 0 and is only raising count when a flip has been made (also, flip is made every iteration as the cases are contained enough)
also, im not casting the toss to a seperate variable but comparing it immediately.

my output was:

```
you got  54  heads, and  46  tails!
exit
```

without listing the seperate flips

Note; this was the first time I ever wrote python. If there's room for optimalisation, let me know!

Answer (score -1):

import random

```
head = 0
tail = 0

flip = random.randint(1 , 10)
if flip % 2:
    print("head")
else:
    print("tail")
```

Comment: What does this answer add to the already existing answers?